# Enable udev and speex support for pulseaudio

Tags: linux-mint, udev, pulseaudio

I tried to install pulse audio, but after running `./configure` I got a warning message:

```
===== WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING =====
You do not have udev support enabled. It is strongly recommended
that you enable udev support if your platform supports it as it is
the primary method used to detect hardware audio devices (on Linux)
and is thus a critical part of PulseAudio on that platform.
===== WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING =====


===== WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING =====
You do not have speex support enabled. It is strongly recommended
that you enable speex support if your platform supports it as it is
the primary method used for audio resampling and is thus a critical
part of PulseAudio on that platform.
===== WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING =====
```

I tried to find information about enabling these two services, but I couldn't find anything. How can I enable them?

Comment: Why try to install it from source when it's available as a package?

Comment: @schaiba if i run `pacmd` and `list-sinks`, i was getting, name as `auto_null` and state as `SUSPENDED'. So i thought there is some problem with pulseaudio and hence i tried to install from source

Comment: Solve that issue first  and let the installed PA in place. You will avoid lots of problems.

Comment: @schaiba can you please give some ideas to solve that issue? i'm using linux for the first time.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't use PA and don't know much about it. But if your package manager offers you software, use it instead of compiling from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not `services`, but compile options, use `./configure --enable-XXX` to enable them (see `./configure --help` first)

Also, to alter compile options for debian based distros, consider the debian way,

First use `apt-get source XXX` to fetch the source code, and use `apt-get build-dep XXX` to install dependencies,

Afterwards, change the `debian/control` file (which contains compile option),

Then at the top source folder, launch `dpkg-buildpackage`, when succeed, you'd see a few deb packages outside that folder, use `dpkg -i XXX.deb` to install it.

Answer (score 6):

You may also need to install the `libspeexdsp-dev` package (which depends on `libspeex-dev`):

```
sudo apt-get install libspeexdsp-dev
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

Comment: These worked for me.